# Flexbox content flowing under main container on mobile only

Tags: html, css, flexbox

On my laptop, all of the content is kept in their respective containers and the heights of each column are fine. When I load the page on my iPhone, the heights become different and content overflows each other and the main content (everything after the first row of events) ends up underneath the white container. [Here](https://highlandk12-thatoneduderob.c9users.io/) is the link if anyone wants to look at the html/css (I'm not sure what's relevant and don't want to clutter the post with code that doesn't need to be here).

[This is what is wrong with the webpage on mobile.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VBgDH.png)

Any assistance is greatly appreciated. I'm very new to flexbox so I apologize for any css code that doesn't make sense.

**HTML**

```
<div class="fluid white large">
                <h2>Welcome</h2>
                <p>Check <a href="#">Grapevine</a> for updated information on Board of Education presentations and topics of interest!</p>
                <div>
                    <hr/>
                    <h2>Upcoming Events</h2>
                    <div class="grid">
                        <div class="fluid">
                            <h3>Wednesday, May 4, 2016</h3>
                            <ul>
                                <li>AP Exam: English Lit & Composition</li>
                                <li>AP Exam: Japanese Lang & Culture</li>
                                <li>AP Exam: Physics 2 - Algebra Based</li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="fluid">
                            <h3>Thursday, May 5, 2016</h3>
                            <ul>
                                <li>Music Booster</li>
                                <li>AP Exam: Calculus AB</li>
                                <li>AP Exam: Calculus BC</li>
                                <li>AP Exam: Chinese Lang & Culture</li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="grid">
                        <div class="fluid">
                            <h3>Friday, May 6, 2016</h3>
                            <ul>
                                <li>AP Studio Art Last Day to Submit Digital Port</li>
                                <li>AP Exam: German Lang & Culture</li>
                                <li>AP Exam: US History</li>
                                <li>AP Exam: European History</li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="fluid">
                            <h3>Monday, May 9, 2016</h3>
                            <ul>
                                <li>AP Exam: Music Theory</li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <p><a class="btn" href="#">View all events</a></p>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <hr/>
                    <h2>News</h2>
                    <div class="fluid n d">
                        <div class="grid">
                            <div class="fluid" style="align-self: center;">
                                <img src="http://highland-k12.org/photos/news/SMALL-SM_1_srcitizendancing.jpg" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="fluid newsLarge">
                                <h3>Sr. Citizen Prom - Evening at Gastby's</h3>
                                <p>Highland CSD and Interact Club Present All Highland Sr. Citizens Welcome! Please RSVP to Carly...</p>
                                <p><a href="#">View the full story...</a></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="fluid n">
                        <div class="grid">
                            <div class="fluid" style="align-self: center;">
                                <img src="http://highland-k12.org/photos/news/SMALL-SMIMG_6264MEDIA.jpg" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="fluid newsLarge">
                                <h3>Music Honor Students Perform in Annual Recital</h3>
                                <p>The Highland High School auditorium was alive with the sound of music during the Eighth Annual Tri-M Music Honor...</p>
                                <p><a href="#">View the full story...</a></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="fluid n d">
                        <div class="grid">
                            <div class="fluid" style="align-self: center;">
                                <img src="http://highland-k12.org/photos/news/SMALL-SMIMG_8095MEDIA.jpg" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="fluid newsLarge">
                                <h3>Highland High School Names Top 10 Scholars in Class of 2016</h3>
                                <p>Highland High School (HHS) has announced the top ten students, including the valedictorian and salutatorian, of the... </p>
                                <p><a href="#">View the full story...</a></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="fluid n">
                        <div class="grid">
                            <div class="fluid" style="align-self: center;">
                                <img src="http://highland-k12.org/photos/news/SMALL-SMIMG959446.jpg" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="fluid newsLarge">
                                <h3>Highland's Soccer Teams Raise Funds for a Team in Africa</h3>
                                <p>The Girls and Boys Varsity Soccer teams at Highland High School (HHS) helped get the ball rolling so that a soccer..</p>
                                <p><a href="#">View the full story...</a></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <p><a class="btn" href="#">View all events</a></p>
            </div>
```

**CSS STYLING...**

```
#container > #brand {
overflow: hidden;
background-color: #3d3d3d;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
list-style: none;
display: -webkit-flex;
display: -moz-flex;
display: -o-flex;
display: -ms-flex;
display: -webkit-box;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: flex;
-webkit-flex-wrap: nowrap;
    -ms-flex-wrap: nowrap;
        flex-wrap: nowrap;
text-align: center;
width: 100%;
}
#container > nav > ul {
display: -webkit-flex;
display: -moz-flex;
display: -o-flex;
display: -ms-flex;
display: -webkit-box;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: flex;
-webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
-webkit-box-direction: normal;
-webkit-flex-direction: row;
    -ms-flex-direction: row;
        flex-direction: row;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
background-color: #3d3d3d;
}
#container > nav > ul > li {
list-style: none;
-webkit-box-flex: 1;
-webkit-flex-grow: 1;
    -ms-flex-positive: 1;
        flex-grow: 1;
text-align: center;
font-weight: bold;
background-color: #3d3d3d;
}
#content {
margin: 10px auto;
background-color: #3d3d3d;
width: 80%;
color: white;
padding: 10px;
text-align: center;
height: 100%;
min-height: -webkit-min-content;
min-height: -moz-min-content;
min-height: min-content;
}
.grid {
display: -webkit-flex;
display: -moz-flex;
display: -o-flex;
display: -ms-flex;
display: -webkit-box;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: flex;
-webkit-flex-shrink: 0;
    -ms-flex-negative: 0;
        flex-shrink: 0;
}
.grid > .fluid {
-webkit-box-flex: 1;
-webkit-flex: 1;
    -ms-flex: 1;
        flex: 1;
text-align: center;
height: 100%;
}
.grid > .large {
-webkit-box-flex: 3;
-webkit-flex-grow: 3;
    -ms-flex-positive: 3;
        flex-grow: 3;
border: 2px solid gray;
min-height: -webkit-min-content;
min-height: -moz-min-content;
min-height: min-content;
}
.grid > .newsLarge {
-webkit-box-flex: 4;
-webkit-flex-grow: 4;
    -ms-flex-positive: 4;
        flex-grow: 4;
}
```

Comment: Please post your code in the question itself. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: That said, some versions of Safari require vendor prefixes for flexbox to work: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35137869/3597276

Comment: @Michael_B I added all of the vendor prefixes and now the container fills all the way to the bottom of the page, but there are major gaps between the content still

Comment: @Michael_B I also added the code to the post. I tried to keep it as relevant as possible.

Answer (score 0):

I SOLVED IT!

Thank you @Michael_B for your help... majorly. I added all of the vendor prefixes and then found an error in my CSS coding (had an extra "height: 100%;" that caused some major spacing issues).

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, **[accept the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)** that you found most helpful.  - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12252027)

Comment: @AshishAhujaツ He didn't post it as an answer, instead a comment, so I added this answer to point it towards his comments. I also added some of the information that I needed to solve my problem. And I can't accept the answer yet.

Comment: You do not need to add an answer to point toward his comments. You can tell him to add an answer, but that's different. As of now, this answer is not fit for SO, and it would be helpful if you delete it. Please read the [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for further details.